# Grpc ssl server crashes - C++

Tags: c++, ssl, server, grpc, tls1.2

I have a Grpc server, written in C++, that works perfect with insecure connection.

Now i am trying to change the connection to use a secured connection so i changed the credentials from *grpc::InsecureServerCredentials()* to *grpc::SslServerCredentials(opts)*, but the server crashes because of segmentation fault.

Here is my code (i used exactly the same code from the grpc examples):

```
        grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
        grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;

        ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = "";
        grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp = {server_key, server_cert};
        ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(pkcp);
        auto server_creds = SslServerCredentials(ssl_opts);

        // builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
        builder.AddListeningPort("localhost:5000", server_creds);

        ServiceListerImpl service;
        builder.RegisterService(&service);
        builder.RegisterService("foo.test.youtube.com", &service);

        auto server = builder.BuildAndStart();
```

i checked server_key, server_cert and they are both valid.

The error stacktrace:

```
stacktrace:
0x1d6265a SSL_CTX_new :0
0x1bfc98c tsi_create_ssl_server_handshaker_factory_with_options(tsi_ssl_server_handshaker_options const*, tsi_ssl_server_handshaker_factory**) :0
0x1bb828a (anonymous namespace)::grpc_ssl_server_security_connector::InitializeHandshakerFactory() :0
0x1bb8ab5 grpc_ssl_server_security_connector_create(grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<grpc_server_credentials>) :0
0x1bb26ac grpc_ssl_server_credentials::create_security_connector() :0
0x1b6c8bb grpc_server_add_secure_http2_port :0
0x1a24bf0 grpc_impl::SecureServerCredentials::AddPortToServer(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, grpc_server*) :0
0x1a3c207 grpc_impl::Server::AddListeningPort(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, grpc_impl::ServerCredentials*) :0
0x1a2b0fb grpc_impl::ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart() :0
```

Tried to get more info with valgrind:

```
==26834== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26834==    at 0x1FBCA18: init_openssl() (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0xCF0C47E: __pthread_once_slow (pthread_once.c:116)
==26834==    by 0x227592A: gpr_once_init (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1FC1089: tsi_create_ssl_server_handshaker_factory_with_options(tsi_ssl_server_handshaker_options const*, tsi_ssl_server_handshaker_factory**) (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1F7CAF9: (anonymous namespace)::grpc_ssl_server_security_connector::InitializeHandshakerFactory() (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1F7D324: grpc_ssl_server_security_connector_create(grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<grpc_server_credentials>) (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1F76F1B: grpc_ssl_server_credentials::create_security_connector() (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1F3113C: grpc_server_add_secure_http2_port (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1DEA56D: grpc_impl::SecureServerCredentials::AddPortToServer(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, grpc_server*) (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1E01B26: grpc_impl::Server::AddListeningPort(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, grpc_impl::ServerCredentials*) (in /home/ofir)
==26834==    by 0x1DF0A78: grpc_impl::ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart() (in /home/ofir)
```

i am running grpc version 1.30.0 on ubuntu 20

I found exactly the same issue here but without comments: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8796

Comment: A crash in SSL_CTX_new seems weird. I'm guessing you've already tried using a default constructed grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions() for debugging. Does it still crash?

Comment: Yes i tried with the default SslServerCredentialsOptions and it still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue when gRPC client crashed in SSL_CTX_new. It turned out this was somehow caused by incorrectly linked openssl when building gRPC. I've rebuilt gRPC with `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package` and it solved the problem.